# Windows SYSTEM user granting READ access to itself - cannot open folder

Tags: java, windows, google-drive-api, acl

This is an odd situation but I'm curious if anyone else has seen this behavior. We're attempting to monitor files in Google Drive in a Windows environment where the user has admin privileges. By default, when GDrive is installed the user that installed it has all READ/WRITE access.

Our application is installed as the SYSTEM user (so that it can monitor files across all users)which does not have READ access to the Google Drive folder... So we are programmatically trying to grant READ access to the GDrive folder.

When we do this as SYSTEM, I update the ACL of the GDrive folder to be set to READ for the SYSTEM user... everything looks like it should (when manually inspecting the security permissions). However, when we try and access the folder an exception is thrown ([FileSystemException](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/winpack/javadoc/com/jniwrapper/win32/io/package-summary.html) using the com.jniwrapper.win32.io class)

However, if I set the SYSTEM READ permission on the GDrive folder using the logged in admin user we are able to access the contents of the folder with no problem. Has anyone seen any behavior like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after looking at the formatted list of ACL permissions using this Powershell command:

`Get-Acl 'C:\Users\user\Google Drive' | format-list`

What I noticed when we were setting READ permission programmatically vs setting it manually is that `SYNCHRONIZE` [AclEntryPermission](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclEntryPermission.html#SYNCHRONIZE) was set when we did it manually. However, we did not include that permission when attempting to do it programmatically... adding that additional permission allowed us to grant READ permissions to the Google Drive folder.